# Lyx can't import Bioinformatics (Oxford journal) Latex file

Tags: lyx

Hi I am trying to import a latex file given hereto lyx. http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/submission_online.html

Lyx is throwing an error. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the bioinfo.cls in the proper directory, such as (on Ubuntu):
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bioinfo/

Then you can make a Lyx layout as --

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this      
#  \DeclareLaTeXClass[bioinfo]{article (Bioinformatics)}

# Read the definitions from article.layout
```

Input article.layout

--
And then put that in the proper directory, namely:
/usr/share/lyx/layouts/

Then make sure you do sudo texhash on the command line, and tools-> reconfigure in lyx, and you should have it set up.

There is a probably with the .eps image (OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps) in Lyx that I can't figure out, don't know if that will cause you problems.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can format text passages as code by using the `{}` button on the top of the editor. Small in line passages you can format as code with the ` accent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am a Mac user and I could not find any folder of the kind you suggested. Do you know what to do over Mac?